# Cannot input correct element in C++ map container

Tags: c++, dictionary

I've got the code:

```
string key = "", value = "", type = "";
while(in)
{
    getline(in, key, '=');
    getline(in, value, '\n');
    getline(in, type, '\n');
    in.get(); // get the dividing empty line
    CommonParamValue *paramValue = CreateParamValue(type);
    paramValue->SetValue(value);
    params.insert(make_pair(key, *paramValue)); // PROBLEM
    delete paramValue;
}
```

When I call `params.insert(make_pair(key, *paramValue));` I get an element of map with correct key end EMPTY value. When I check

```
paramsIter = params.find(paramKey);
    if (paramsIter != params.end())
    {
        if( ("" == paramsIter->second.GetValue())
        ...
    }
```

All the time condition `"" == paramsIter->second.GetValue()` is true, but it must not be so!
Additional information:

```
class CommonParamValue
{
public:
    virtual void SetValue(string value){}
    virtual string GetValue(){ return ""; }
};
class StringParamValue : public CommonParamValue
{
    string str;
public:
    StringParamValue(){}
    virtual void SetValue(string value){str = value;}
    virtual string GetValue() {return str;}
};
CommonParamValue* Report::CreateParamValue(const string &strType) const
{
    if (strType == "int")
    {
        return (new IntParamValue());
    }
    else if(strType == "string")
    {
        return (new StringParamValue());
    }
    else
    {
        // error
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

The question is why when I do `params.insert(make_pair(key, *paramValue));` I always get an element with correct key and an EMPTY value? What is wrong?

Comment: You have encountered something called _slicing_. See e.g. the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) for some more information.

Comment: Polymophism always does its trick by a pointer, not by an object! What you have done is inserting an object with a type of CommonParamValue into a stl map, so all the additinal information in StringParamValue is lost!

Comment: Maybe you should declare params as std::map<std::string, CommonParamValue*>, so you can just call params.insert(make_pair(key, paramValue)), of course, you should delete that object lately when you're sure it won't be used anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the `map` is declared as:

```
std::map<std::string, CommonParamValue> params;
```

The insertion will result in the slicing of the value, to a `CommonParamValue` which always returns a `""` from `GetValue()`. To obtain the desired behaviour the value would in the `map` would need to be a pointer to a `CommonParamValue`, preferably a smart pointer:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<CommonParamValue> > params;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right of course. I didn't know that special feature of C++.

Answer (score 0):

The object inserted into the map is a `CommonParamValue` not a `StringParamValue`, that means that the copy of your objects inserted into the map get *sliced* to `CommonParamValue`.

Change your map definition to have a (smart) pointer or reference mapped.